# ¿Cómo llevar un control de acceso php dando accesibilidad al usuario?

Tags: php, sesiones

Espero pueda darme a entender. Realizando una página web php necesité de un control de acceso que maneje por medio de mysql.

Con cada acceso se pide la contraseña de usuario; esta página debería de mostrar resultados de consultas. **¿Qué se puede hacer para obtener esos resultados sin comprometer la seguridad de la página?**. Estoy comprendiendo php y aún no me he adentrado en estos tipos de temas.

Intenté llevar el control cambiando un campo de una tabla de tal forma que si ese campo muestra un resultado negativo el usuario debe de iniciar sesión.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias, realizare el recorrido

Comment: a que te refieres con comprometer la seguridad?

Comment: Cuando hago consultas dentro de una página estas las tengo guardadas dentro de otras páginas, lo que quiero es que, si por algún motivo algún usuario llega acceder a las otras páginas no se le permita el acceso manteniendo a el usuario dentro de la página principal, o algún proceso que permita hacer uso de sesiones o algo parecido que también impida el acceso a cualquier usuario

Answer (score 2):

espero esta información te pueda ayudar.

Necesitas utilizar las sesiones de PHP.

Primero debes crear un archivo `(login.php)` que procese y valide el usuario accediendo a la base de datos con MySQL, que verifique si existe o no ese usuario con privilegios.

Debes agregar una condicional que verifique los datos si el usuario y la contraseña son correctas para luego crear la sesión de seguridad y redireccionarlo a la zona admin segura.

Ej: Archivo de procesamiento `login.php`

```
<?php
// Inicia el archivo con esta función que inicia una nueva sesión  
session_start();  

// Empiezas por recibir la info del formulario con método POST y realizas una consulta con esos datos  
// Suponiendo que ya tienes la conexión a la base de datos y
// Utilizando el objeto mysql o la función mysqli_query()
// Creando la variable $sql para la consulta
$sql = "SELECT usuario, contrasena FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '{$_POST['usuario']}' AND contrasena = '{$_POST['contrasena']}'";

// Validamos si la consulta es correcta
if( $resultado = $mysqli->query( $sql ) === true ){  

  // Si es mayor que 0 quiere decir que el usuario existe
  // en la base de datos con esas credenciales
  if( $resultado->num_rows > 0 ) {  

    // Inicia las sesiones con sus credenciales
    // Esto es como una especie de Cookies de sesión seguras
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $_POST['usuario'];
    $_SESSION['contrasena'] = $_POST['contrasena'];

    // O bien agrega este otro valor
    // El valor puede ser un String encriptado
    $_SESSION['autenticado'] = 'connect_true';

    // y por último redirecciona a la página principal
    // header('admin');
  } else {  
    // Notifica que hay un error con su usuario y contraseña.  
  }  
}
```

Por último crea un archivo llamado verificador.php donde vas a agregar lo siguiente, validando la variable `$_SESSION['autenticado']'

Este archivo debes agregarlo en todos los archivos que quieras proteger y que sean solo para usuarios privilegiados o con rol admin.

```
<?php
// Inicias esta función  
session_start();  

// Luego agrega la condicional para verificar que existe el valor guardado en autenticado  
// Si la sesión autenticado NO tiene el valor de 'connect_true' en String normal  
// o encriptado (Puedes agregar algún método que encripte) puedes agregar  
// puedes retornarlo al inicio para nunca pueda acceder
 if( empty($_SESSION["autenticado"]) || $_SESSION["autenticado"] != 'connect_true') {  

  // Devuelves al inicio siempre que no sean usuarios logueados o algún intruso...  

}
```

Referencias:

http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php
http://php.net/manual/es/session.examples.basic.php

Comment: es bueno que intentes ayudar, pero la idea es que el OP muestre su avance de código y partir de ahí para ayudarle

Comment: Si tienes razón, pero ahí le dí un pequeño ejemplo para que pueda comprender un poco como puede crear los archivos para hacer verificaciones de seguridad.